# Trying to run my MVC5 site on IIS it keeps saying Access is Denied

Tags: mysql, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-7

I am trying to run my mvc 5 website application on my IIS windows Server 2012

I get the following message

Access Is  Denied for user root@localhost

Any tips will be appreciated

Comment: `root@localhost` is not a Windows username.

Comment: It's for mysql. My application is using mysql and that's the error I get when trying to connect

Answer (score 0):

Solved. You cannot have a semi colon character in your password